Unable to read cookie in Laravel project
I have a larval project i am trying to store some user data in a cookie, However when i try to read it from the other controller i am getting NULL value, i am unable to read the cookie Please help me with any suggestion to fix
Code to create cookie:
   ` $cookieData = [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'login_status' => true, 
            ];

            // Create a cookie with a one-day validity
            $cookie = cookie('user_info', json_encode($cookieData), 1440);
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Authentication successful'])->withCookie($cookie);

`

Code used to read the cookie:
    `$abc=$request->cookie('user_info');
            $value = Cookie::get('user_info');
        
        if (Cookie::has('user_info')) 
    {} `

click to view Debugger output 
exempted the cookie from encryption from middle ware, route is also set on web, still the code is unable to read the cookie

When you run this code in a browser, does the cookie get set or not ?

Do you see this cookie in de dev tools in your browser?
